# How do I get the name of the file being passed in as a command line argument in KSH or Bash?

Tags: bash, ksh

For example:  if I have

```
$ readFile.sh < info
```

How can I get the script:

```
echo "Reading the contents of $1!"
```

to give me the name of the file?  Am I going about this in the total wrong way?

I am new to ksh and shell scripting in general and I dont know how to google this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using input redirection you cannot easily get the name of the file from which standard input is being read. (In general, there may not even be a file, since standard input could be coming from the standard output of another command.)

If you were to call your script as

```
readFile.sh info
```

then `$1` would indeed expand to the name of the argument, `info`.

---

I say "easily" in the first paragraph, since it's technically possible (in a platform-dependent way) to find out the name of the file behind the file descriptor used for standard input. But when you need this information, it's an indication that your script should take a filename argument rather than reading from standard input.

Answer (score 2):

(On systems supporting [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs))  In order to obtain the name that the script is reading from (assuming that you are reading from the file, i.e. `bash scriptname < somefile`:

```
readlink -f /proc/$$/fd/0
```

This wouldn't work if the input is coming from `STDIN`.

Comment: This assumes an operating system that supports the `/proc` file system.

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to get that filename.

Your standard input might not be a file at all; it might be a pipe.

The file might have been unlinked and thus no longer have any name in the filesystem.

If you want to do it non-portably, and your system has the `lsof` command, you could do this:

```
filename="$(lsof -F -p $$ -a -d 0 | grep ^n | sed 's/^n//')"
```

If you're on Linux, you can use `readlink` on `/proc/self/fd/0` (see devnull's answer).

Otherwise, rewrite your script to take the filename as its first argument (see chepner's answer).